# Definite/zero article with plural

Tags: definite-article, singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

I'm still struggling to outline the difference between "the+plural" and "zero+plural"

> 1. There was a football (soccer) game last night and I couldn't fall asleep
> 2. because **fans** at the stadium were cheering loudly
> 3. And I also could hear **players** kicking the ball

both "fans" and "players" are expected to be in this context and have been already introduced by the word "football game" in the sentence #1 (as well as "the ball"). I obviously can reliably use "the fans" and "the players"
However, as I understand it, we can still use zero article in both #2 and #3.

1. Are both "zero" and "the" idiomatic here? What is the best choice of articles in #2 and #3?
2. if both "zero" and "the" are possible what difference in terms of meaning can you feel between "players/the players", "fans/the fans"?

Comment: It's difficult to identify any *specific* shift in meaning here, even though as a native Anglophone I would *expect* the definite article before both **fans** AND **players** in this context. So I would ***look*** for some difference if I knew the article-less version came from a competent native speaker (since I'd assume he had some ***reason*** for the slightly unusual phrasing). I can't think of any credible intended difference right now - but I know I don't need to because *this* text is from a non-native speaker (as positively identified by the unusual position of **also** :)

Comment: It depends on whether some fans or all fans were making a noise. And likewise who you heard kicking the ball. "The fans" means all the fans at the game, "fans" means some of them. (Although in practice you don't know whether it's some or all, so there's an element of custom or inference, whether you view the fans as a collective group or just some different people.)

Comment: @StuartF but as a native speaker you would use "the" in both sentences, right?

Answer (score 1):

> There was a football (soccer) game last night and I couldn't fall asleep
> because *the* fans at the stadium were cheering loudly

*The* means you expect the listener/reader to know *which fans* you mean - fans relating to a context you just established with the words "there was a football (soccer) game".

Without *the*, you don't establish a link between *fans* and anything previous you said.  The implication then is something else other than fans could be cheering loudly.  Because it doesn't often make too much sense for things other than fans at a soccer game to be cheering, it sounds awkward or like you are a computer AI that does not understand what a soccer game and its basic elements (players, fans, ball, field, etc.) is.

Comment: I don't buy this. Even without ***the** [fans]*, it's explicitly stated that the relevant fans are ***at the stadium*** - and it's contextually obvious that stadium must be near wherever the speaker lives. So short of the speaker listing the names and addresses of all the noisy fans, I don't see how they can be any more *specifically* referenced. I think you're trying to *invent* a convincing alternative meaning based on the absence of the article before ***fans*** - but I'm not convinced.

Comment: It's bordering on a meaningless distinction, but you could perhaps make a case for saying that if the specific determiner ***the*** is not present, it's at least *possible* to postulate an unstated determiner ***some** fans* (i.e. - making the point that not ***all*** the fans were noisy).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So the listener here is lucky because the speaker/writer has provided a lot of context - between the words "football (soccer) game", "stadium", and "cheering loudly", you can't come to any other conclusion.  This doesn't make the *the* optional though, which is something an English language learner may not understand.  Can you say "I was at a park and couldn't ride merry-go-round"?

Comment: The definite articles before ***fans*** and ***players*** in your question are both optional (but would *normally* be present, as per my first comment under the question). The articles before ***stadium*** and ***ball*** (and ***merry-go-round*** in your above comment) are ***required***.